# Dependency property in datatemplate not updating

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

We have a custom control with two dependency properties, Round and Depth. The problem is when I use that control in a datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SyntDom" DataType="{x:Type entities:SwapInstrument}" >
...
    <depthOfMarket:DOMControl Grid.Row="1" Instrument="{Binding}" Margin="10,5" Round="False" Depth="38">
...
</DataTemplate>
....
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SyntDom}" Content="{Binding Instruments.Instrument1}"/>
```

then Round property is never updated with False value, while Depth gets its 38. 
When I use DOMControl directly without wrapping it with ContentControl it works okay.

The code for those properties in control is pretty much copy-paste, so I doubt problem is there.

upd: dependency properties definitions

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DepthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Depth", typeof (int), typeof (DOMControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnChangedDepth));
public int Depth
{
    get { return (int) GetValue(DepthProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DepthProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnChangedDepth(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ((DOMControl) obj).OnChangedDepth();
}

private void OnChangedDepth()
{
    _dom.Depth = Depth;
    BindGrid();
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty RoundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Round", typeof (bool), typeof (DOMControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnChangedRound));

public bool Round
{
    get { return (bool) GetValue(RoundProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RoundProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnChangedRound(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ((DOMControl) obj).OnChangedRound();
}

private void OnChangedRound()
{
    _converterVolume.Round = Round;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ´updated with False value`? Does that mean updated is `True`?

Comment: I mean when I debug it, I can see that the Round property of control is set to true (I guess its when the control initially created on form), but it never gets the False value which I put into xaml.

Comment: Show us the declaration of your DPs please.

Comment: Oh, Round set to true in control constructor. But nevertheless, its never set to False.

Answer (score 0):

So I had my Round property defined as

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RoundProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Round", typeof (bool), typeof (DOMControl), 
          new PropertyMetadata(OnChangedRound));
```

I've changed it to

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RoundProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Round", typeof (bool), typeof (DOMControl), 
          new PropertyMetadata(true, OnChangedRound));
```

i.e. defined a default valyue for property, and it works ok now.